# It is given that $X_i \sim^{\text{ind}} \text{Gamma}(\alpha,p_i)$ Find the distributions of $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{X_1+X_2+...+X_i}$, where $i=2,3,..k$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

It is given that $X_i \sim^{\text{independent}} \text{Gamma}(\alpha,p_i)$

Find the distributions of $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{X_1+X_2+...+X_i}$, where $i=2,3,..k$

I have done it for $k=3$, by doing the transformation $X_1=Y_1, X_2=\frac{Y_1 Y_2}{1-Y_2}, X_3=\frac{Y_1Y_3}{(1-Y_2)(1-Y_3)}$
But the Jacobian calculation and joint pdf is quite tedious to find.
It will be more difficult to find for $k$ by this procedure.
Please help.

Comment: You should use the transformation $Y_1=X_1+X_2+X_3\,,Y_2=\frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2}$ and $Y_3=\frac{X_3}{X_1+X_2+X_3}$ for $k=3$.

Comment: I had posted this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317941/showing-z-is-are-independent-if-z-1-sum-i-1n1x-i-and-z-i-fracx-i) on CV.

Comment: Ok, so taking $Y_1= \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i$ seals the deal

Comment: How did you know about this transformation? Or what was your intuition?

Comment: The transformation is given in the question itself. Choosing $Y_1$ to be the entire sum $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ would possibly make things easier seeing that the $i$th partial sum is the denominator in $Y_i$ for $i\ge 2$.

Comment: Did you mean joint distribution? The individual distributions are quite easy to find.